# Use autofilter to copy visible cells to variable

Tags: excel, vba, range, autofilter

I'm using AutoFilter to delete some rows before a different macro is run. One of my filters brings up some notes that I need to save for later pasting. I assume saving it to a variable will allow me to then delete those rows and paste them when needed later. Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub Test()
    With Sheet1
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With Range("A10", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            On Error Resume Next
            .AUTOFILTER Field:=1, Criteria1:="=(**", Operator:=xlFilterValues
            'Insert code to copy values to variable here
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I can't figure out how to copy the visible cells to a variable. Tried using xlCellTypeVisible but it didn't work.

Comment: So I figured it out. Going to post solution for anyone's future reference.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. Here's the code below

```
With Sheet1
.AutoFilterMode = False
With Range("A10", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    On Error Resume Next
    .AUTOFILTER Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Device*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.delete
    .AUTOFILTER Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Manufacturer", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.delete
    .AUTOFILTER Field:=1, Criteria1:="=(**", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Set MyRange = Sheet1.Range("A10: I" & Cells(Rows.Count - 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    CalVal = MyRange
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.delete
End With
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

This deletes the rows I needed deleted while saving the ones that start with "(".

Later I paste it on sheet 2 after everything else has been copied.

```
'Paste Notes
NumRows = UBound(CalVal, 1) - LBound(CalVal, 1) + 1
NumCols = UBound(CalVal, 2) - LBound(CalVal, 2) + 1
Set Destination = ws2.Range("A" & lastRow).Offset(1, 0)
Destination.Value = "Table Notes"
Destination.Font.Bold = True
Set Destination = ws2.Range("A" & lastRow).Resize(NumRows, NumCols).Offset(2, 0)
Destination = CalVal
```

Need to Dim MyRange, CalVal, LastRow, NumRows, and NumCols of course